# Как сделать так, чтобы элементы тега select при нажатии перекидывали на другой URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы при клике на определённый option в select`e пользователя перекидывало на другой юрл адрес.

Вот HTML:

```
  <select class="sort-by">
    <option class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Замовчуванням</option>
    <option id="js-sort-l2h" class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Зростанням ціни</option>
    <option id="js-sort-h2l" class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Спаданням ціни</option>
  </select>
```

JS:

```
let sortl2h = document.getElementById('js-sort-l2h');
let sorth2l = document.getElementById('js-sort-h2l');

sorth2l.setAttribute("href", "?sort=h2l");
sortl2h.setAttribute("href", "?sort=l2h");
```

Это всё что мог сообразить, но, как понимаете, оно даже близко не работает

Comment: Работать это естественно не будет, так как Вы пытаетесь задать атрибут `href` для `option` который в свою очередь не имеет такого атрибута. Если же Вам нужно добавить параметр в URL, то сам параметр добавьте в value для нужных Вам `option` и уже на `onchange` селекта получаете этот `value` и используете где Вам необходимо.

Comment: как вариант - использовать вместо `select` набор `div'ов`, внутри которых и разместить ссылки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<select class="sort-by" onchange="document.location.href=this.querySelector('option:checked').dataset.link">
    <option data-link="/link-1" class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Замовчуванням</option>
    <option data-link="/link-2" class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Зростанням ціни</option>
    <option data-link="/link-3" class="sort-el">Сортувати за: Спаданням ціни</option>
</select>
```

В опциях задаете нужные вам ссылки через data аттрибуты, а через событие onchange отслеживаете, какая опция стала checked и получаете значение, указанное в data-link, это значение передаете в document.location.href, что приводит к редиректу на указанный адрес.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сделать по-человечески вот так:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.target.form.submit()
})
```

```css
.vis-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="sort">
    <option value="">Сортувати за: Замовчуванням</option>
    <option value="h2l">Сортувати за: Зростанням ціни</option>
    <option value="h2h">Сортувати за: Спаданням ціни</option>
  </select>
  <input type="sbumit" value="Search" class="vis-hidden">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select')

select.value = location.href.replace(/^\w+:\/\/[^/]+/, "")

select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  location.href = e.target.value
})
```

```css
h1 { display: none }
:target { display: block }
```

```html
<select>
  <option hidden disabled selected>
  <option value="/js">root
  <option value="/js#aaa">aaa
  <option value="/js#bbb">bbb
  <option value="/js#ccc">ccc
</select>

<h1 id="aaa">Aaa</h1>
<h1 id="bbb">Bbb</h1>
<h1 id="ccc">Ccc</h1>
```